# What are the best network adapter settings for low-latency trading?

Tags: tcp, network

What are the best network adaptor settings for low-latency trading from a server connected to 10+ counterparties via cross-connects having < 1ms latency?

Latency is much more important than throughput for this application - anything that delays messaging is bad. More CPU utilization is fine. This machine has 36 physical and 72 logical processors.

These are current settings:

- Interrupt Moderation - Disabled (do not want delays due to less frequent interrupts)
- Large Send Offload - Disabled
- Max Number of RSS Processors - 16 (should I increase it?)
- Max Number of RSS Queues - 8 (should I increase it?)
- Encapsulated Task Offload - disabled
- IPv4 Checksum Offload - disabled
- TCP Checksum Offload - disabled
- Flow Control - Auto Negotiation (should I disable either Rx or Tx?)
- Receive Buffers - 1024 - should I increase or decrease this? do higher values cause latency? (do want to avoid TCP retransmits)
- Transmit Buffers - 1024 - same as above
- Receive Side Scaling - Enabled
- Recv Segment Coalescing - Disabled - this reads like it adds latency as it collects packets from TCP/IP stream and combines them into larger packets

I am not a network engineer so appreciate your input!

Edit: Adaptor is Intel Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE backplane.

Comment: I doubt there's one "this works in all setups" answer here. It will depend on the hardware used, the operating system, application and the device with which you're communicating (and it's hardware, operating system, and software).

Comment: still, there should be some reasonable answers which may contain caveats. At the moment i'm mostly interested in the Transmit/Receive buffers and what affect increasing those could have on latency / Retransmits.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 1):

In the range of 1 ms, the NIC latency doesn't really do much. A generic 10G NIC has a latency of some 10 µs.

Fiber, DAC links or backplane (-R 64b/66b large block code) can be ~1 µs faster than 10GBASE-T due to less encoding overhead.

The specifics depend on the NIC at hand. If there are no recommendations you may need to test it yourself.

That said, offloading usually helps. IRQ moderation often increases latency. Flow control can mess up everything, stay clear. Optimal buffer sizes depend on the workload/flow sizes and should have no impact on latency. Larger buffers usually don't hurt.

The largest impact on latency is in the driver (version) and the host IP stack - tune and test. Virtualization - obviously - is a big no go. With a multi-socket host you'd want to pin NIC (no *Receive side scaling*), application and memory to a specific socket or as few sockets as possible - host configurations are off-topic here however.